# Highlight cursor after changing buffer in vim

Tags: vim, cursor, highlighting

While using vim I have trouble finding my cursor quickly after entering another buffer, especially if I have many splits open.

I fixed this by writing a function which is called by an autocmd when a buffer is entered. The function matches and unmatches a few characters around the cursor, waiting in between using `sleep`.

However, this gets annoying when switching quickly and a lot, or e.g. when opening a help tag, since my function is called **after** entering the buffer but **before** jumping to the help tag, so it appears late.

How can I achieve my goal without significantly slowing down vim?

**EDIT**: I worked around the help tag part by checking against the help filetype in my highlight function. However this is still not optimal.

This is my function:

```
function! HlCursor()
    let l:pat = '\v.{0,3}%#.{0,3}'
    " Let it blink for 250ms
    let l:match = matchadd('Todo', l:pat)
    redraw | sleep 250 m
    call matchdelete(l:match)
    redraw
endfunction
```

Comment: How do you think we will fix your function if you don't show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to your blocking sleep would be to only remove the highlighting on a following event. To do that, after the `matchadd()`, just define another (fire-once; i.e. one that deletes itself) autocmd that clears the highlighting, and return from the function. Suitable events would be `WinLeave,CursorMoved,CursorMovedI,CursorHold,CursorHoldI`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the built-in "cursorline" and "cursorcolumn" options? Then, you can use two autocmds: a BufEnter or WinEnter autocmd to do `setlocal cursorline cursorcolumn` and a CursorHold,WinLeave autocmd to do `setlocal nocursorline nocursorcolumn`.

Comment: I see now the two-autocmd method is basically what Ingo suggests to fix the delay issue, but this will also allow fixing that the wrong position gets highlighted when jumping to tags.